# What does extension Joomla K2 do?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

****Can anyone tell me in, *human understandable language*, what extension Joomla K2 does?****

I see this popup as a "popular" extension, but don't have a clue on what it does.

The discription states: "The powerful awarded content extension for Joomla! with more than 1.2 million downloads so far (and counting!)". And below is a list of features below.

**I feel like missing out something. Why should I use this, explained in a few simple words.**

Best Regards,

Comment: You should read this: http://getk2.org/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K2 is basically an extended and feature rich version of your default Joomla article manager. It comes with many more features, making life easier for administrators to manage their content on their website. It also integrates with a lot of other 3rd party extensions. Some of the key features that K2 includes are:

- Commenting system
- Tags (handy for a blog)
- Drag n Drop
- Extended user profiles
- Powerful API

So to answer your question simply, it's better to use K2 as it prevents having to install multiple 3rd party extensions such as Community Builder *(just an example)* for extended profiles and JComments *(just an example)* for the commenting system.

Have a look at the [K2 Site](http://getk2.org/) and even give it a test to what what you can achieve with it.